# Regedit does not ask for password when started as administrator

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-registry, uac

I needed to change the access rights to the system log on two computers (both running Windows 7), as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274018/system-security-securityexception-when-writing-to-event-log). I did it successfully on one of the computers.

On the second one, I started regedit.exe as administrator from the context menu. It did not ask for a password on start, although I was logged in as a non-administrator. I added the user and groups I needed to the access list, then I clicked "Apply". I got an "access denied" error message with just an "OK" button, and there was no UAC prompt where I could have given an admin password (or possibly a domain admin password - one of the accounts which needs access came from the active directory) to resolve the issue.

When I log in with my administrator account, the same thing happens - regedit starts, but it will not let me add user permissions, not even for local accounts.

What could be causing this, and how do I add the users?

Comment: What does the current Access control list look like? Who has which rights? Are you sure you are logged in as a *local* admin!?

Comment: Are you logged in as `Administrator` or just as ***an*** administrator?  If the latter, try doing “Run as Administrator”.

Comment: It is the second, and this is *exactly* what I did - by "started regedit as administrator from the context menu" I mean that I chose "run as administrator" from the context menu, and no matter which account I was using - with or without local administration rights - I never got an UAC prompt.

Comment: By the way, we were able to edit the registry after somebody logged in with an account with domain administration rights. I will leave the question open, because we never found out what prevents the UAC from appearing.